# Webpack imports-loader with messageformat and angular-translate

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, webpack

I'm having some difficulty making `angular-translate-interpolation-messageformat` play nice with the `imports-loader` for `MessageFormat`. I outline the issue in [this issue](https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate/issues/1068).

Copied:

---

Even though the module is exposed using UMD (yay) it is actually using the global `MessageFormat` object [here](https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate/blob/master/src/service/messageformat-interpolation.js#L38). This is forcing me to either expose `MessageFormat` onto `window` (which I would prefer not to do), or make a workaround with webpack (which is also cumbersome). The real solution is to use UMD correctly and not depend on globals but rather require things correctly.

Here's what the UMD format looks like now:

```
(function (root, factory) {
  if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
    // AMD. Register as an anonymous module unless amdModuleId is set
    define([], function () {
      return (factory());
    });
  } else if (typeof exports === 'object') {
    // Node. Does not work with strict CommonJS, but
    // only CommonJS-like environments that support module.exports,
    // like Node.
    module.exports = factory();
  } else {
    factory();
  }
}(this, function () {

// interpolation-messageformat code that uses the global MessageFormat variable

}));
```

Here's what it should look like:

```
(function (root, factory) {
  if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
    // AMD. Register as an anonymous module unless amdModuleId is set
    define(['messageformat'], function (MessageFormat) { // <-- changed line
      return (factory(MessageFormat)); // <-- changed line
    });
  } else if (typeof exports === 'object') {
    // Node. Does not work with strict CommonJS, but
    // only CommonJS-like environments that support module.exports,
    // like Node.
    module.exports = factory(require('messageformat')); // <-- changed line
  } else {
    factory(root.MessageFormat); // <-- changed line
  }
}(this, function (MessageFormat) { // <-- changed line

// interpolation-messageformat code that uses the global MessageFormat variable

}));
```

Thanks!

---

So, until that issue gets resolved, I need to do a workaround. I'd really prefer to avoid globals. Here's my current solution with the `imports-loader`:

```
require('imports?MessageFormat=messageformat!angular-translate/dist/angular-translate-interpolation-messageformat/angular-translate-interpolation-messageformat');
```

With that, everything builds fine, however, when I open Chrome, the app breaks when running the `angular-translate-interpolation-messageformat` function that uses `MessageFormat` saying that `MessageFormat` is not defined

**Here's where things get weird...**

If I open the app in any other browser (other than Chrome) it works just fine. Also, if I open the app when it's deployed, it works fine (even in Chrome).

**Here's where things get weirder...**

If I open my Chrome DevTools and *then* open the local app in Chrome, everything works just fine. o_O

So, anyway, I'm wondering if maybe I'm using the `imports-loader` incorrectly or something. Any help appreciated!

Comment: Thanks for your help, I also needed to use imports-loader, similarly as you. Do you know if this will be ever fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using by any chance `devtool: 'eval'`? I've seen that same weird behavior you describe, and it went away switching to `devtool: 'source-map'`.

Comment: Changing to `source-map` fixes the problem! Thanks! Is there a bug reported for it already that you're aware of?

Comment: Nope. My project was pretty complex, so I wasn't really sure what was introducing the issue. Do you have a small repro case?

Comment: Unfortunately not :-( Luckily the maintainers of `angular-translate` are on it and they've already fixed the bug. So I just have to wait for them to push a new version and I'm set. Thanks again!